# Android: Can't make small fontsize on programmatic textviews

Tags: android, textview, size

I'm using the following method which programatically creates a linearlayout and populates it with two textviews, adds text and then turns it into a drawable that I later use a layer above a shape. However, I've noticed that I can't create a small fontsize - it seems stuck at a minimum size which is relatively.. large, and anything that I specify below that value just seems to make it look increasingly blurry (but still the same size). What could be the reason for this?

This behavior occurs whether or not I used TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP.

Edit: This size stays the same even if I specify something ridiculous like:

```
.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 60);
```

it doesn't get any bigger - it just gets "sharper".

Edit 2: If I specify the top textview as having a very large size, then the smaller I set the second textview, the smaller it becomes - as a ratio (for example, if I set the top at 100 and the bottom at 50 it looks exactly the same as the top at 10 and the bottom at 5). However, in no way can I reduce the size of the top textview.

Edit 3: If I remove one of the textviews, and leave only the other one as a single textview in the layout - I can't change the size at all. I can only make it more or less blurry depending how low I set the number but it will always appear the exact same size on screen.

```
  private Drawable createTextLayer() {

    LinearLayout newLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    newLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    newLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    newLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.somecolor));

    newLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    TextView headlinetv = new TextView(getContext());
    TextView bodytv = new TextView(getContext());

    headlinetv.setText(headlineText);
    headlinetv.setTextSize(7);
    headlinetv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    bodytv.setText(bodyText);
    bodytv.setTextSize(6);
    bodytv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    newLinearLayout.addView(headlinetv);
    newLinearLayout.addView(bodytv);

    newLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    newLinearLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    newLinearLayout.layout(0, 0, newLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), newLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    newLinearLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(newLinearLayout.getDrawingCache());

    newLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
}
```

Comment: setTextSize uses COMPLEX_UNIT_SP by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be quite tricky and took me several hours to solve, but I'm posting the answer for anyone else who ends up in a similar situation.

The cause: 
The entire drawable layer was the uppermost layer above a shape, and was therefore stretched to the size of the shape no matter what. In order to stretch it to the size of the shape, the largest view was stretched (essentially, the longest textview) and therefore couldn't be enlarged or reduced in size.

The solution: 
I defined two more textviews, gave them the longest string by 1 character, and made the textcolor transparent. I would have preferred to give them blank space as content but android refused to measure a textview containing whitespace, so it had to be actual text. I put one textview at the top and one at the bottom and thus the visible text appears perfectly centered and in the correct font size.

Edit: 
There turns out to be a better way of doing this. Define the textview as the same size as the shape on which it sits as a layer and define padding around the textview (play around with it to find the minimal amount of padding needed). If you have several textviews, divide the size of the shape by the number of textviews and give each one a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 7);
```

Change the font size of 7 to any font size as you wish.

Comment: that should work.. but in practice doesn't. I can only reduce the size of the lower textview - and only as a ratio of the upper textview. The size of the upper textview always remains constant